# Sum the number of lines from different files

Tags: bash, shell, sum, increment, cat

I need to sum the number of lines from different text files like: x_red, x_green which have some information inside of them, and this is what I got:

```
counter=0

colors=`cat manyColors.txt`

addPrefix(){
   echo "x_$1"
}


for color in colors
do
#   cat `addPrefix $color` | wc -l  # will give me the nº of lines just fine
   counter=$(($counter + cat `addPrefix $color` | wc -l ))
done
```

So yeah, the counter isn't really incrementing properly and I have no ideia how to sum those arguments properly, what am I missing here?

Edit: Also, how can I turn 
    " cat `addPrefix $color`|wc -l ", into a variable?

Edit2: Added the function and changed the function name, for misunderstandings.. Sorry I know it's still kinda confusing

Comment: Also what is `changeColor $color`? Is it come command?

Comment: It's a function which will return the name of a text file, sorry about the confusion , just came up with some weird names.
It'll just add a prefix to the input argument like:
changeColor red   --> x_red , which is an existing text file in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using $(...) syntax, you do not need to reference your inner variable with a $.

You should be able to simply use

```
    COUNTER=0
    for color in colors
    do
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER + $(cat $(changeColor $color) | wc -l`)))
    done
```

Be sure to embed your cat function within the $(command) since you cannot use nested backticks.

Comment: Thank you and thank you anubhava for the help.
Just a quick question, can I eventually turn "cat `changeColor $color` | wc -l" into a variable? Is it doable?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. If you mean inside the for loop for readability you definitely can. I would use the local keyword http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html. Alternately you can create a function that takes a color and outputs the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `counter=` line you can use this code in BASH inside your `for` loop:

```
(( counter += $(wc -l < $(changeColor $color)) ))
```

There is no need to use `cat` here.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply, Im sorry for being kind of stubborn with this but Im still curious, is there a way to use cat on this situation?

Comment: And why do you want to use useless `cat`?

Comment: If you really want it the use: `(( counter += $( cat $(changeColor $color) | wc -l) ))`

Answer (score 0):

I find your question unintelligible, but if, as your title suggests, you want to sum the lines in multiple files, you can do that quite easily like this:

file1:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

file2:

```
line 1
line 2

cat file[12] | wc -l
5
```

The trick is not to pass the filenames to `wc` but just pass all the files as a single stream on its `stdin` (by using `cat`) then it cannot count, and give totals for each individual file. Compare this:

```
wc -l file*
   3 file1
   2 file2
   5 total
```